# alexa skill to place call

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I have a database of customers details with their phone numbers, I want to develop a skill where my customers can place calls by searching that database.

I referred this  [link](https://forums.developer.amazon.com/questions/85084/how-to-use-alexa-skill-to-place-a-call.html) and found that calling skill can be implemented, but as far as I know, there's no documentation available for it, so if anyone could guide me through how calling skill can be implemented that would be helpful.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally, Amazon developers have [responded](https://forums.developer.amazon.com/questions/116360/alexa-skill-to-place-a-call.html), that it is not possible to call anyone through Alexa , we can always use 3rd party APIs though.